# What is the native way of implementing Publish Subscribe between Android widgets?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a custom EditText and a TextView in an Activity. The custom EditText traps for key presses and calculates the number of character entered and wants to publish the character count to the TextView. Should I use the java.util.Observable/Observer way? Or is there a more native android method to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable`/`Observer` is probably fine in the abstract.

For `EditText`/`TextView`, you could use `addTextWatcher()` rather than subclassing `EditText` to support your character count.

And bear in mind that you should really test this stuff with the soft keyboard, as I am under the impression that per-keystroke event behavior changes when users use the soft keyboard instead of the G1's QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: Hah! You're too late. I already am subclassing EditText. :) I will investigate the TextWatcher method.